# Unexpected assertion error of Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm quite new in usage of Sinon.

Suppose we have module ( named myModule.js ) definition :

```
//myModule.js
var _f2 = function() {
    console.log('_f2 enter');
    return {prop1:'var1'};
};

var f1 = function(){  
    var  myVar1  = _f2();
    console.log('_f2 called'); 
};

module.exports._f2  = _f2;
module.exports.f1  = f1;
```

And here is test for the module

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var myModule = require('./myModule');

describe('test my module',function(){
    var f2Spy ;
    beforeEach(function(){
        f2Spy = sinon.spy(myModule,'_f2');
    });
    afterEach(function(){
        myModule._f2.restore();

    });
    it('call _f2',function(done){
        myModule.f1();  
        sinon.assert.called(f2Spy);

        done();
    })
});
```

When running this test , I got assert error that _f2 was not called:

```
AssertError: expected _f2 to have been called at least once but was never called
```

But from log messages I can see that _f2 was called. 
The question is : what cause to the error ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you modify your module this way, then the test will pass:

```
var f1 = function(){
    var  myVar1  = exports._f2();
    console.log('_f2 called');
};
```

(By the way, using `exports` in my code above is equivalent to using `module.exports` given the code you've shown.)

The problem with your original code is that there is no way for other regular JavaScript code to intercept direct calls to `_f2` that are made inside your module. Sinon is regular JavaScript code, so it cannot intercept direct calls to `_f2`. If you make your call through the `exports` table, then there is an opportunity for Sinon to patch this table to intercept the call.

Comment: Thanks for quick and helpful reply